# getting error in vb.net

Tags: vb.net-2010

AM using vb.net.in button click i redirect to some other page. in that page load have some code to check whether the mysql table contain data for particular date or not. if the table contain data i want display msg like " the table contain data for the particular date.
when i run this code am getting error.

my code:

```
Dim offset As Integer = -1
    txtd1.Text = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, offset, Today)



    If txtd1.Text <> String.Empty Then
        Dim dataexist As New SECSALETableAdapters.pro_dataexistSECSALETableAdapter
        Dim dtexists As SECSALE.pro_dataexistSECSALEDataTable = dataexist.GetData(Convert.ToDateTime(txtd1.Text).Date)

        If dtexists.Rows.Count = 0 Then




            ---------
         else
          msgbox("data already present for the particular date")
         end if
        end if

table contain data for the particular date. but am getting the message in the msg box.am getting error when i run this code.
```

error:

> Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

table structure:

```
fld_id      int(11) NO  PRI     auto_increment
fld_msg     longtext    YES         
fld_phone   varchar(20) YES         
fld_date    date        YES         
fld_status  varchar(45) YES     0   
fld_type    varchar(45) YES         
fld_name    varchar(50) YES
```